# Insert into two tables at same userID at same time

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I want to add data in two tables in one go.

I have two tables, **UserCredentials**(userid,username,password,userrole) and **EmployeeRecord**(userid,username,firstname,lastname,desgination,nationality)

UserId is identity in both tables generated in DB, I am looking for a way that I can get userID in EmployeeRecord at which record is inserted so that I can insert login credentials at same userId in UserCredentials table. Both records need to be inserted at same time.

This is what my code looks like right now:

```
      create procedure enteremployeerecord ( 

            @firstName varchar(100),
            @lastName varchar(100),
            @desigNation varchar(50),
            @natioNality varchar(50),
            @userName varchar(50),
            @userPassword varchar(50),
            @userRole varchar(50)          
            )
  as
  begin

  insert into EmployeeRecord(username,firstname,lastname,designation,nationality)
  values (@userName,@firstName,@lastName,@desigNation,@natioNality)

  insert into UserCredentials(username,password,userrole)
  values (@userName,@userPassword,@userRole)
```

And here is LINQ SQL code in C# (Not sure though how it will change for two queries )

```
EmployeeRecordDBClassDataContext con = new EmployeeRecordDBClassDataContext();
con.enteremployeerecord(firstNameTextBox.Text, lastTextBox.Text, desginationTextBox.Text,nationalityTextBox.Text,userNameTextBox.Text, passwordEmployeeTextBox.Text, userRoleTextBox.Text)
```

I am using VS 2012 & SQL Server 2012

Comment: why don't you just create a `Trigger`

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you really shouldn't be storing passwords in plain text. You need to use a salted hash instead.

Comment: Your tables also suffer from denormalization. You have the userrole in the credentials table. This prevents a user from having more than 1 role. Also the username should NOT be in more than 1 table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UserId is identity in both tables generated in DB

Bad idea.  Only one table needs to be responsible for the identifier.  Otherwise you'd have to add a LOT of protective measures to ensure that records are *always* added to both tables simultaneously.

For illustration, let's assume that `EmployeeRecord` is responsible for generating the `UserId`.  To insert into `UserCredentials` just get the generated ID and insert it:

```
@DECLARE @userID int  

insert into EmployeeRecord(username,firstname,lastname,designation,nationality)
values (@userName,@firstName,@lastName,@desigNation,@natioNality)

SELECT @userID = @@SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into UserCredentials(userid, username,password,userrole)
values (@userid, @userName,@userPassword,@userRole)
```

Also, with a logical 1:1 relationship between tables (which is impossible to implement in SQL since you can't insert to two tables simultaneously) I would question whether or not the tables should be merged into one.  If there's no reason to keep them separate then *don't separate them*.